# Livecode 7.0.5 Stack Script Editor Hangs

Tags: livecode

I've just started using Livecode 7.0.5 (I was on 6.7.1 for a long time) and I can't get the script editor to work with the stack script.  When I open a card script I can edit the script (save etc) but when I try to open the stack script Livecode becomes non-responsive (beachball of death). None of the code is displayed - just the heading; "revNewScriptEditor 1" and the name of the stack.

The stack is quite significant (over 30,000 lines of code). I don't have any problems compiling and saving an executable for iOS7 although it did take a long time (2-3 mins).

Has anyone else experienced this? Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

you really should report this behavior to the Livecode team vs posting it here.